# JSON parse returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, stomp

I'm receiving a STOMP message with some JSON data, the problem is that I one case the code that I'm using works

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            console.log("data -->" +greeting + " <-- data");
            console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body) + " <-- JSON object");
            console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content + " <-- parsed data");
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

the result

```
data -->MESSAGE
content-length:34
message-id:4wb1eunw-1
subscription:sub-0
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
destination:/topic/greetings
content-length:34

{"content":"user has subscribed!"} <-- data
[object Object] <-- JSON object
user has subscribed! <-- parsed data
```

And I'm using almost the same code in another project

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/golden/notification', function (notification) {
            console.log("data -->" +notification + " <-- data");
            console.log(JSON.parse(notification.body) + " <-- JSON object");
            console.log(JSON.parse(notification.body).content + " <-- parsed data");
            showNotification(JSON.parse(notification.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

But the result is somehow different

```
data -->MESSAGE
content-length:39
message-id:wh4z1ahx-0
subscription:sub-0
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
destination:/golden/notification
content-length:39

{"notification": "user has subscribed!"} <-- data
[object Object] <-- JSON object
undefined <-- parsed data
```

I'm a bit new to Js so the answer may be really simple but i can't findany solutions to solve this problem.

P.S. this script is part of a Sring Boot application and the librarys are the same.

Comment: I guess the second response doesn't have a `.content` property there

Comment: I'm so dumb. Probably need to go to sleep and continue working with a clear head. Thank you so much @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @CertainPerformance. As you see in the first example my JSON object had an element "content"

```
{"content":"user has subscribed!"}
```

And it got its value by using `JSON.parse(notification.body).content`

But in the second example, there was no element "content" only "notification"

```
{"notification": "user has subscribed!"}
```

So to get the value of "notification" you need to use `JSON.parse(notification.body).notification`

I hope that this post will be helpful for someone.